# Returning Most Frequent Character(s) in a String

Tags: c#, dictionary

Trying to achieve this using a Dictionary. Currently, I have this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the character(s) with the highest occurence in this string.  
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">the tring containing the characters</param>
/// <returns>the character or characters with the highest occurence</returns>
static char[] GetMostFrequentChar(string str)
{
    var chars = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    List<char> mostCommon = new List<char>();  
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars.ContainsKey(str[i]))
        {
            int curr = chars[str[i]];
            chars[str[i]] = curr + 1; 
        } else // character not in dictionary 
        {
            chars.Add(str[i], 1); // initial count for an added character is 1
        }
    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> entry in chars)
    {
        if (entry.Value == chars.Keys.Max())
        {
            mostCommon.Add(entry.Key); 
        }
    }
    char[] result = mostCommon.ToArray();
    return result; 
}
```

It's supposed to return an array containing the most frequent character(s), but I seem to get an empty array whenever I run this method on an input string. Where did I go wrong?

I know there are ways to do it without a Dictionary, but I'm curious how it works with a Dictionary.

Comment: `if (entry.Value == chars.Keys.Max())` I think you meant `chars.Values.Max()`

Comment: @KevinGosse I feel super dumb. Thank you so much. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin Gosse already give you the answer, but you could simplify your code a bit  like this:

```
private static char[] GetMostFrequentChar(string str)
{
    Dictionary<char, int> chars = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (chars.ContainsKey(c)) chars[c]++;
        else chars.Add(c, 1);
    }

    int max = chars.Values.Max();
    return chars.Where(b => b.Value == max).Select(b => b.Key).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the heck, here's a `Linq`-approach with a `Dictionary`

```
static char[] GetMostFrequentChar(string str)
{
    Dictionary<char, int> result = str.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
    return result.Where(x => x.Value == result.Values.Max()).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
}
```